# How to update NSURL from dispatch_queue_t?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsurl, void

I have some problem with dispatch_queue_t queue. I tried to found perfect solution for my problem but i found solution for load UIImage or another elements but not for NSURL. So i have simple NSURL with simple site:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"site.ch"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

I need that my NSURL (This code which up)will reboot after for example 10 min, so for time i put NSTimer, but for update this NSURL i tried to used this code but i have error also..

```
-(void)updateRadio

{

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSError* error = nil;

        NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"site.ch"]
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];        
        // checking if error == nil would be appropriate

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    });

}
```

SO i need to put NSURL With Request to this code with dispatch. Not NSString only NSURL 
How this made?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have error because of incorrect encoding. Try to use NSUTF8StringEncoding instead.

Comment: I need to put NSURL(first code in my question) to dispatch for perfectly update URL from internet.